# Adding firebase analytics on old source code, duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I need to add a firebase analytics feature in an old android source code after adding `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'`,
I am receiving this error.

```
 duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller.class
```

I already did this,

```
 compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'( {
     exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
 }
```

but firebase is asking for a preconditions library

```
dependencies {
compile('org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2') {
    exclude module: 'commons-io'
}
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
    exclude module: "httpclient"
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
//Helper
compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:2.0.2'
compile 'biz.kasual:materialnumberpicker:1.2.1'
//UI
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.0.3'
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile files('libs/crittercism_v4_5_3_sdkonly.jar')
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2'
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post all the dependency?

Comment: @DhavalSolanki, hi, i already edited my question with dependecy list. thanks